# What is this aloe-like plant?

Tags: identification, succulents, aloe

After searching a little, I think it is a hybrid aloe x gasteria, aka gasteraloe, maybe gasteraloe superba.

Here are the pictures:

[image]

[image]

One of its babies, if this helps:

[image]

And its flowers:

[image]

What species or hybrid is it?

Comment: do the leaves actually have raised warts that make the white pattern, or just whitened, slightly transparent areas that create it? Hard to tell from your photos

Comment: These are not raised warts, the leaves are smooth. The pattern is just created by whitened areas (not really transparent). I can add close-up pictures of the leaves if necessary.

Comment: In that case, I think your own ID of Gasteraloe superba is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

From [helpful gardener](http://www.helpfulgardener.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18573) it looks like a [**Tiger Aloe**](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=tiger+aloe+&qpvt=tiger+aloe+&qpvt=tiger+aloe+&qpvt=tiger+aloe+&FORM=IGRE).

The gel tht's inside can be used for hand cream--softening dry skin.

Hope for you it will [bloom like this](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/aloe-vera/caring-for-tiger-aloe.htm)!

[image: Tiger Aloe Blooming]
Keep us posted.

Comment: They're indeed similar, but I don't think they're exactly the same, looking at other pictures. Tiger aloes seem to have darker leaves, an their shape is somewhat different. There are tons of Aloes, Gasterias and hybrids, which makes it sometimes difficult to identify them!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a Gasteraloe. It's very similar to my Gasteria verrucosa  X Aloe variegata. (There really aren't pictures of it online so I've included a picture of mine).  Sometimes it's sold as a cheap ripoff to people who think their buying the more rare Aloe dinteri, which is similar.

[image]

Comment: Yes, your plant looks like mine. At least the shape of the leaves and the white patterns on them are similar. I've added a picture of the flowers.